# Multiple computer Windows update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

In our company we sell our devices together with **AiO** (All-in-One) computers that we buy from electronics vendor. Usually we make like 10 pieces series. My current task is to update all the bought computers to the newest version of Windows. Is there a way how to make it easier and faster? The update takes forever. This fall we will make a series of 50 devices so it would be great to find a way how to make it faster.

I was thinking of simply updating just one PC and then flash it into the other once but we need the computers to have individual license and number etc. Or I was thinking of reinstalling from the bottom all the computers, but I am not familiar with the way how Windows licenses works and it would be dumb to buy new Windows licenses when we paid for 'em already in price of the **AiO** computer. Big companies have to have some way of installing and updating computers in great numbers. I highly doubt that they have someone like me that just sits and watches computers and waits for them to be ready.

Would you know how to make it faster or how is it done in big companies?

Thank you very much

Comment: Best to use the windows 10 upgrade assistant on each PC.

Comment: If you're buying PCs in bulk - check if your vendor would do the imaging for you with a 'default/master' image you supply

Comment: Microsoft has software that allows you to remotely manage hundreds of devices.  Have you considered using that software?